What is ECS Fargate "Average Duration"?
I was trying to prepare a Total Cost of Ownership for using ECS Fargate using the AWS Pricing Calculator. While doing so I came across the parameter "Average Duration". If i want my service to run 24/7, should i select the average duration as 365 days?

If you want to calculate it by 24/7 uptime, just put in 730 hours or 1 day.
The calculator will do its thing.
Average Duration: 730 hours

Average Duration: 1 day(s)

It won't let you enter 365 days.


THank you for the response. If i need to host 60 tasks, what vCPU should is recommended? The cost comes to 0 for 1, 2 & 4 CPUs but shoots up to 1M USD for 8 vCPUs

Did you double-check the Number of tasks or pods field? I was also creating an estimate and when entering the same configuration as one of my ECS services the cost was significantly higher than what I'm currently paying. The trick was on setting the mentioned field as 2 per month (assuming that no auto-scaling will happen but keeping a task per AZ for high availability), after that, the price was similar to my current bill.

730 hrs or 1 day? are they both not different? 24 hrs or 1 day makes sense! How can 730 hrs be replaced by 1 day?!!
